# Get XML Element By Index Rather than Tag

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest, getelementsbytagname

I'm creating a video library and have an XML document split up by video category such as:

```
<video>
    <comedy>
        <url>bla</url>
        <title>blabla</title>
    </comedy>

    <action>
        <url>bla</url>
        <title>blabla</title>
    </action>
</video>
```

And so on. I use an XMLHttpRequest to getElementsByTagName() for the genre I want and it is working fine.

My question is: I want to create a 'Most Recent' category, that would just pick the first 16 (or however many) off the top of the XML file, regardless of category. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the childNodes of the root-element, and check if the node is a element-node(childNodes will also return textNodes for the whitespaces)

```
var doc=xml,//the xml-document
            childs=doc.documentElement.childNodes,
               i=-1,
               j=16;//how many nodes you like to get

    while(j && childs[++i])
    {
      if(childs[i].nodeType===1)//check if we got a element-node
      {
        j--;
        //do something with the element
        console.log(childs[i].tagName);
      }
    }
```

In some browsers there may also be a children-property which only returns children that are element-nodes, but this is no standard so I wouldn't suggest to use it.

When you use a library like jQuery it would be much easier, to have the same result you only need:

```
$('>*:lt(16)',xml.documentElement)
  .each(function(i,o){console.log(o.tagName);});
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response. i'm trying to add the children to an array but it doesn't seem to be working.

basically when selecting genres, I have x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(genre);

and then i work with x from there.

in your while loop, I changed it to j<16 where j starts at 0, then inside the loop I have:
x[j] = childs[i];

but it doesn't seem to be working. any thoughts? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
 xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

    XmlElement ele = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;

    if (ele.HasChildNodes)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < ele.ChildNodes.Count; c++)
        {
            DisplayInfo(ele.ChildNodes[c]);
        }
    }


static void DisplayInfo(XmlNode node)
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < node.Attributes.Count; a++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes[a].Name + " : " + node.Attributes[a].Value);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(node.Value);

            for (int c = 0; c < node.ChildNodes.Count; c++)
            {
                DisplayInfo(node.ChildNodes[c]);
            }
        }
```